# Why is div moving in hover state?

Tags: html, css

I have two divs and why those divs are moving while hovering?

**HTML**

```
<div class="two">
  <label class="one">
    <input type="radio"> Sanjeev
  </label>
  </div>
  <div class="two">
  <label class="one">
    <input type="radio"> Hari
  </label>
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.one{
  border:1px solid red;
  display:block;
  opacity:0.5;

}
.two{
  margin-bottom:5px;

}
.two:hover{
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

[Link to my code](https://jsbin.com/rotiwat/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: I want border on hover too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because on hover you're adding a border which is changing the dimensions of the div.

You can fix this by setting a transparent border before the hover.

```css
.one{
  border:1px solid red;
  display:block;
  opacity:0.5;
}
.two{
  margin-bottom:5px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}
.two:hover{
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="two">
  <label class="one">
    <input type="radio"> Sanjeev
  </label>
  </div>
  <div class="two">
  <label class="one">
    <input type="radio"> Hari
  </label>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by assign a border transparency

[see demo](https://jsbin.com/seyatupasi/1/edit?html,css,output)

```
.two {

  border:1px solid transparent;
}
```